# Backing up Windows to a NAS: Security issues

Tags: windows-7, backup, nas

Recent computer malware will seek out mounted SMB volumes and do their dirty work on files it finds there. This puts NAS-based backups at risk. Due to a Windows limitation, a client may use no more than one set of login credentials to connect to a single NAS device, no matter how many volumes are on that device. "Hidden" volumes aren't really hidden.

So the question is: If I set up a new NAS device, dedicate it for backups, and set up Windows backup (from 7, 10) to use a volume on that NAS with a dedicated set of credentials, what can I do on the client to be sure the volume connection and credentials are not cached or otherwise available to malware?

EDIT: In other words, if I'm running Windows Backup service and configure it to connect to a NAS as a particular user, when it runs, is it possible that the logged-in user will be able to access the same NAS volume?

Comment: Why do normal users have read and write access to volumes which contain your backup archives?  You also should be creating external backup archives.  The malware can only encrypt files it can actual write to.  So don't allow users to write to any volume you cannot risk losing in the first place.  Design your recovery plan accordingly.  The user(s) which have write access to your backup volumes should not be accessing any file that could be malware.

Comment: Make sure the NAS share is accessible only the user account under which the backup process runs, and use a dedicated account just for running the backups. I.e. create a new user account, grant this account all required access on the NAS and then run-as the backup under it. That's it.

Comment: @Angstrom See my updated question: when Windows runs its backup service, does it run it within some kind of isolated container, completely independent of the currently logged-in user?

Comment: @Ramhound " The user(s) which have write access to your backup volumes should not be accessing any file that could be malware" that's what I'm trying to design. My experience with Windows goes back to the days where it was a single-user OS. I'm not sure it "works properly". See my edited question.

Comment: Share connections is a property of a user *session*. As I've said above - create new user account of the computer, add it to the Backup Operators group, switch Windows Backup service to run under it and then grant this account access to your NAS. Done. You now have the backup process fully isolated from the rest of the system, so whatever share connections it has won't be visible to anyone else on the machine.

Comment: PS. Just test the damn thing already. It takes all but 2 minutes to set it up.

Comment: @Angstrom How do I test being logged on to a Windows workstation with two different user sessions simultaneously?